# How to find TPU name and zone in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, google-cloud-tpu

I am trying to run a code that requires tpu name and zone in config.

Using a TPU runtime, how can I find the TPU name and zone in Google Colab?

Answer (score 1):

Google Colab doesn't expose TPU name or its zone.
However you can get the TPU IP using the following code snippet:

```
tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()
print('Running on TPU ', tpu.cluster_spec().as_dict())
```